# What happens when my transaction gets confirmed and added to the new block?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin

> What happens when my transaction gets confirmed and added to the new block?

I learned that if it doesn't get confirmed it will be stuck in the mempool. And I know that the miner who added the new block will be rewarded with currencies and the tx fees that is included to the block. But I was wondering if there is no reward to the transaction owner?

Can anyone give me an answer?

Comment: Is the term "confirmed" means that the transaction can now successfully be sent to the destination address? So if I want to send for example some BTC to somebody else, my transaction has to be confirmed from a minor, right? Now I see why fee bumping exists.

Answer (score 0):

Transaction owner buys the service. Block producers (miners) sell the service.

Transaction owner cannot be paid for the service that they are buying, because it does not make any sense.